# Adding some code to T4 to validate special characters

Tags: t4, t4-toolbox

I want to validate each and every value that is being passed to database for special characters. Is it possible to have any method kind of thing in T4 achieve this rather than adding a static method and validating it or please do let me know if there's a better solution for this

Comment: I can't answer this question but from a design standpoint I'd recommend against this.

Comment: Any reason just curious 

Comment: Basically I agree with the philosophy of [Terrence Parr on StringTemplate](http://www.stringtemplate.org/about.html):  "If your template looks like a program, it probably is--you have totally entangled your model and view."